# Make ISO file to install W7 and our software being the Windows just background

Tags: .net

I'm a programmer for Indra and I need to make an ISO image to install a software we have made here along with the Windows 7 using the Windows installation data (the folders, files and so on) and our .WIM files generated here for our software. In the end what we would like to achieve would be every time the customer runs the computer our software appears in the screen but it is running in Windows, but you don't see the OS, it's in the background. Right now I have accomplished to make the image and install but I just get the Windows 7 installed, I can't see my software or find it, do you have any tips about what I should do to make this works? Could you help me out?

Looking forward for your answer.

Thank you very much,
Juan.

Comment: You want an ISO image, that installs Windows 7 then, launches your **kiosk mode** application?

Comment: Hi Jondrell. What I need is to install a desktop app we programmed in .NET along with the W7 software being both of them, our software and W7, in the same ISO. To do that I have to create a .WIM file which will include W7 and my software but I don't really know the structure the ISO should have to work properly. In the end the desired would be every time somebody starts a computer where I installed this disc they see directly the welcome menu of our app and not Windows, Windows would stay just in the background.

Comment: This isn't really a .net question or even a programming question.

Comment: You are right Jondrell, it's not, but I can't find how to do it, I really need it and I thought maybe here somebody knew and could tell me... I'm sorry about it's not a programming question.